# Change Laravel base URL from localhost to localhost/laravel5

Tags: apache, laravel

I'm trying to change **Laravel** base URL to localhost/laravel5, I tried to change **APP_URL** variable in **.env** file, I did the same changes to this line in **config/app.php** file:

```
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost/laravel5')
```

And here my **/etc/apache2/sites-available/laravel.conf** file:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost/laravel5

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/laravel5/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/laravel5>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I also tried to restart **apache2** service, but nothing changes

Comment: You want to have your home page at `http://localhost/laravel5`?

Comment: Yes, as I mentionned, I want to change my project's default URL to http://localhost/laravel5

Comment: You could just make your route to point to your homepage...is that an option? for example Route::get('/laravel5', function () {
    return view('your_page');
});

Comment: No, because I want to change project's default URL and not only homepage URL

Comment: i don't know if you can have a subdomain for your ServerName, i think you must have something like laravel5.com or .dev but without subdomain

Comment: I believe the `APP_URL` config value is only used by the console because it cannot determine the URL from the incoming request. But I may be mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Make your virtual server like this in apache

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName laravel5.app
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/laravel5/public

        <Directory /var/www/html/laravel5/public>
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and run

```
sudo a2ensite laravel5.app
service apache2 reload
```

Finally, make sure to edit your `/etc/hosts` file and add an entry for `laravel5.app`:

```
# other entries...

# your entry...
127.0.0.1    laravel5.app
```

And then you can access your app at http://laravel5.app

Comment: you are missing 1 crucial step :)

Comment: and which one is that?

Comment: the change in the hosts file

Comment: but I want to use localhost/laravel5 for this app, and localhost/someapp for another app, and in this case I can't

Comment: How do you see your app on a live server? When you put that in production how is that link going to be....you can't have localhost there!

Comment: You will have to use a subdomain...something like localhost.laravel5.app

Answer (score -1):

I recommend You to use something like Homestead or Valet for developing [Check the docs here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/valet#valet-or-homestead)